# How to open specific page on FCM push notification IONIC-3?

Tags: ionic3

I want to open a specific user chat page on push notification click in FCM when app is in background.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {

  if (data.wasTapped) {
     this.nav.push("PageName")
  }
})
```